# Python OpenCV: capture.read returns true, although camera unplugged

Tags: python, opencv

I have camera, i use cv2 module in python. Everything works fine, maybe except i would like to have error codes or success/failure returned instead of printed out to stderr.

I have loop which reads images and its return.

```
while True:
    ret, img = capture.read()
    print ret
    ........
    time.sleep(0.033)
```

According to OpenCV's docs it should return False on failure. While it works, it's fine. When i unplug webcam (to 'simulate' some failure) this results in many outputs of "VIDIOC_DQBUF: No such device", but the ret is still True. Is this a bug, a webcam or OS specific behaviour? Are there any workarounds on this? (instead of redirecting stderr within python and checking what's on there)

Comment: This bug is still present in version 3.1.0 for Windows x64 Python 2.7. However, it is not present in 2.4.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is supposed to return False on failure, but seems it doesn't work reliably in your case. I can suggest a workaround. I assume that when the webcam is unplugged the returned image is all zero. You can check that too in conjunction with the returned flag.

```
while True:
    ret, img = capture.read()
    print ret and (not img.any())
    ........
    time.sleep(0.033)
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, although after unplugging, the last image remains (when i print it out it prints the matrix). I might be able to keep comparing the matrixes of current and last (simple == doesn't work, probably different references). Or maybe I could somehow 'flush' the capture?